# Which AWS S3 retrieval model would be cost-effecient?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am looking at this question and have a different opinion:

A company is to run a service on AWS to provide offsite backups for images on laptops and phones. The solution must support millions of customers with thousands of images per customer. Though the images will be retrieved infrequently, they must be available for retrieval immediately. Which is the most cost-efficient storage option that meets these requirements?

```
Options:
A.  Amazon Glacier with Expedited retrievals
B.  Amazon S3 Standard Infrequent Access
C.  Amazon EFS
D.  Amazon S3 Standard
```

Correct Answer:

`B. Amazon S3 Standard Infrequent Access`

The question is asking the most cost-efficient storage option, which should be Glacier.Option A indicates not only Glacier but also states the option of Expedited retrievals which will deliver the data in 1-5 minutes

S3 retrieval pricing (not including Glacier Expedited):
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Glacier Expedited retrievals pricing:
https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/pricing/

Though the actual cost could be heavily determined by the data volume, however in general, I believe the expense saved by Glacier would compensate the extra cost from Expedited retrieval service.

Answer (score 1):

**AWS Glacier** is incorrect as you can't directly put objects to the Glacier, to do so you first need to upload to S3, then with life cycle policy move to Glacier. So it will definitely increase the cost.

**EFS** is wrong, as it has a very slow read/ write.

**S3** standard has somehow equivalent pricing and speed but Infrequent access is the best option in this case.

In real scenario it will be a good idea to place Cloudfront in front of S3 bucket as files are static and you can save cost on read operations by caching the.

Comment: Thank you matesio on explaining Glacier, shouldn't it be understood to use Glacier right after the data is uploaded into S3? you mentioned life cycle, the life cycle is configurable, right? can't people config it to go to Glacier right after it is uploaded in S3?

Comment: yes, but Glacier is recommended for archival purposes, also if you notice at the question it asks recommendation w.r.t 2 points, Pricing and access time. Just imagine in this era would you like to revisit a site that takes more than 20 sec to load? So how can we wait for even 1 minute for a single object?

Comment: @matesio I agree that Glacier isn't right for this use case, but your statement that you *"first need to upload to S3, then with life cycle policy move to Glacier"* is based on outdated information and is no longer correct.  S3 has supported the ability to upload objects directly to the Glacier storage class since November, 2018: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/amazon-s3-amazon-s3-glacier-launch-announcements-for-archival-workloads/

Comment: Also, the people who complain about EFS performance have not -- it seems -- read and understood [how it is designed to work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html).  The more you store, the faster it is, so at the scale of this question, EFS is not wrong because of speed.  It is primarily wrong because of price.  S3 IA is cheaper.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the input, why you say S3 IA is cheaper? Wouldn't Glacier be the cheapest? occasional retrieval need (which can be done by expedited retrieval but add extra cost) can be compensated by the low cost of Glacier, meaning overall Glacier should be the best option. Any missing here?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I agree, EFS is burstable, performance increases with an increase in metered size. But how can someone afford to wait to increase its size? I did choose EFS for the same use case but the performance was really pathetic and we had to move to S3 bucket for better performance. Again it depends upon use case and for the question asked above EFS can't be a good fit for both performance and pricing. 
One more thing I would like to add is EFS support Provisioned throughput so you don't need to worry to wait for an increase in size but that is really costly.

Comment: @mdivk Glacier does not meet the requirement that *"they must be available for retrieval immediately"* because the delay for an expedited retrieval -- however brief -- simply does not qualify as "immediately."  Additionally, it costs more to initially create an object in Glacier, which is $0.05 per 1000 objects instead of $0.01 per 1000 objects for Standard_IA, but I believe the disqualification of Glacier hinges on the choice of the word "immediately."

Answer (score 0):

Credit to all the participated discussions:

```
Category     Storage Cost    Retrieval Time Cost
S3 Standard: Regular         Immed
S3 IA:       Low             Immed
S3 Glacier:  Lowest          1-5 min with Expedited Service
```

In reality, the decision is to be made upon balancing various requirement;
For this question, IA is the right answer